# Open and Closed mapping Examples

Tags: continuity, open-map, closed-map

I am looking for three mappings f:X to Y  any set of topology on X or Y. so very flexible. 
Can you help me find an example of a function that is 
(a) continuous but not an open or closed mapping 
(b) open but not closed or continuous
(c) closed but not open of continuous

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $X$ has the discrete topology, every function from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous, and every subset of $X$ is both open and closed. If you choose $Y$ so that it has a subset that isn’t open and a subset that isn’t closed, it’s not hard to get your first example. (You can even take $Y$ to be $X$ with a different topology.)

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is an open bijection; then it’s not hard to show that $f$ is also closed. Essentially the same argument shows that a closed bijection is always open. Thus, for the other two examples we cannot use bijections. It turns out that we can use an injection, though.

Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology, let $Y=\{0,1,2\}$, with the increasing nest topology

$$\tau=\big\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{0,1\},Y\big\}\;,$$

and let $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$; this will work for one of the other two examples, and I’ll leave it to you to work out which one it is. Finally, you can use $X$ and $Y$ and a different injection from $X$ to $Y$ to get the remaining example.

Comment: Thank you so much. As f(X)={0,1} in that example this  maps an open set to an open set and there are no other open sets it must be an open mapping? and is not a closed mapping using the same logic as X is closed and it maps to an open set. sorry for the comment I am just trying to make sure my reasoning is okay.

Comment: @Jm222222: You’re right about the open sets: the only open sets in $X$ are $\varnothing$ and $X$, and they both get sent to open sets in $Y$. However, you need to do a bit more to show that $f$ is not a closed map. It’s not enough to show that it takes a closed set to an open set, because that open set might also be closed. (Remember, a set can be both open and closed.) However, it’s true that $f[X]=\{0,1\}$ is not closed in this case, because $Y\setminus\{0,1\}=\{2\}$ is not open in $Y$.

Comment: what is wrong with the function that maps the whole real line to a subset of R whose range is finite of numbers in the real line? If the target subset is a single value then thats its a continuous function, otherwise its not...right?

Comment: Why is "If X has the discrete topology, every function from X to Y is continuous" correct? To my understanding in the discrete topology if $p$ is the limit point then the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(p)$ will always be 1 unless $f(x)=f(p)$. Therefore, every epsilon less than 1 won't work and thus the every function on the discrete metric is not continuous. Where did I go wrong?